# Media Scaling on short portrait pages issue with Google Cloud Print

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-cloud-print

I am writing a program that automatically prints labels for our laboratories with all of the appropriate information.  The labels are printed by a Brother QL-710W label printer and the label printing is initiated by Google Cloud Print.  When printing to pages that have a greater height than width (i.e. if I am using a small width label tape and printing LANDSCAPE, there are no problems; however, if I try to print in portrait with a shot height, the page scaling has issues.  I am posting a picture here to illustrate the problem.

[image: As page height decreases, page scales oddly]

The image at the left (top as displayed) has the appropriate scaling for this print-out, I made the page height the same as the width.  For the middle image, I lowered the page height to about 2/3 of the page width and you can see the page content being scaled and the left and right margins being expanded.  Finally at the appropriate page height, almost no room is left for the page content.

Note: when I print the page using the browser print dialog, I am able to print the image as expected, though it does have two pages instead of one that can be overcome by selecting only one page to print (see image here).
[image: Browser printed]

The Google Clout Print ticket looks like this:
    var ticket = {
     version: "1.0",
     print: {
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      },
      copies: {copies: 1},
      media_size:{
      width_microns:62000,
      height_microns:22860
      },
      page_orientation: {
        type: "PORTRAIT"},
       margins: {
         top_microns:0,
         bottom_microns:0,
         left_microns:0,
         right_microns:0
      },
       page_range: {
        interval: 
          [{start:1,
          end:1}]
       }
     }
    };

The cloud print is initiated by a "Print" button that builds the page content as a blob:

```
"content"   : HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).getBlob(),
```

Ways that I have tried to remedy the situation:

- I have made the margins of the print out 0 as seen in the ticket
  above.
- I have also tried to edit the media and print css:

  "@media print{header nav, footer {display: none;}}"+
  "@page{margin:0pt !important; padding:0pt !important; size:2.4in 0.9in;}"+

  - I have tried making the div elements smaller, but as you can see from the affect made by even small changes to the page height (middle image) this has little effect.

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Hi, I got the similar situation, did you found any solution?

Comment: Not yet Vipin Kohli.  Still problem-solving... Keep me posted if you find something.

Answer (score 0):

When you print (successfully) from the browser, the browser converts the content to PDF before sending it to Cloud Print. Since that works, but tries to print a second (blank) page, my guess is that whitespace is creeping in below the content you're interested in.

I suggest you take a good look at the HTML blob, and also consider converting the HTML to PDF. PDF has much higher fidelity for situations like this (view in browser; send to Cloud Print black box; print on a label printer).

Comment: Thanks Jacob!  converting to pdf alone did not fix the problem.  In fact, the  printout was even smaller.   I'm investigating the blob now.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a limitation of Google Cloud Print.  When I print from the browser through the cloud print instead of local printer, the page is also prints shrunken down.  Swap the printer  back to the local printer and it ends up the correct size.

Comment: Is the PDF that you converted exactly what you want? Meaning, are the dimensions correct? Is there any undue whitespace?

Comment: There is white space on the PDF as well.  I read somewhere that adding a  transparent border to the body might help; I'll try that on Monday.  I can't check the feature from home...

Comment: Are you able to fix the margin issue ?

Comment: Ok so I've managed to remove the whitespace by embedding the output in an iframe and setting the metaTag; however, while that made printing exactly as planned work for the local printer, when printing through the Google Cloud Print service, the page is still scaled inappropriately...   HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=209px, initial-scale=1')

Comment: I tried removing everything except the following html:
<html><body style="overflow:hidden; "></body></html>
CSS:
body {border: 1px solid black;margin:3.0mm; width:50mm; height:16.0mm; overflow:hidden; }

I have tried transforming the html and body, rotating it and printing landscape, changing the height/width.  No matter the settings, I always get similar results.  If I make the body size larger than the paper size, it will still print with the same box in the middle of the page, but won't expand to include the overflow.  Conclusion: GCP generates margins on its own.  Not sure if controllable.

Comment: Any better solutions, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ive been doing countless tests trying to figure out why images are being printed with a border when its set to borderless printing.

This may help. 
The same source file was printed, results:

JPG: borderless yes, force raster yes, printed 5mm thick border.
PDF: borderless yes, force raster yes, printed 4mm oversized for paper.
PDF: borderless yes, force raster no, printed 2mm thin boarder.

HTML images seem to be handled like jpg images.

Fit and shrink to paper options dont change the above results.